# Process Builder running on all -not based on criteria

Tags: process-builder

I am trying to set up a Process in Process Builder to start when new leads are added (or existing leads are updated with the criteria below) that have a specific campaign ID populated (using campaign ID 18 characters) and custom field date of today (current day lead is uploaded). This is an external list. However the process is running on ALL leads new and modified with and without the following criteria it should only start when both of these are true on the Lead.
[image]

The error message on these is:  *Error element myDecision (FlowDecision).
The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.Campaign_Name__r.Id because it hasn't been set or assigned.*

But these Leads are not even part of the campaign. The process is set for when all conditions are set and Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record - Yes.
Thank you for assistance with this!

Answer (score 1):

So, Process Builder is trying to see if the DML'd Lead meets these criteria

- `Lead.Campaign_Name__r.Id` not equal null AND
- `Lead.X5_Tou... = TODAY`

You need to do the following to avoid traversing a lookup relationship that is not populated:

- `Lead.Campaign_Name__c` not equal null AND
- `Lead.X5_Tou... = TODAY`

`Lead.Campaign_Name__c` is the foreign key field on the Lead and it will always be available to any PB evaluation on Lead - but if null, the relationship to the parent record `Campaign_Name__c` doesn't exist and hence `Campaign_name__r.Id` can't be resolved (and PB blows up)

`Lead.Campaign_Name__c` is by definition the same as `Lead.Campaign_Name__r.Id` if and only if the value of `Lead.Campaign_Name__c` is non-null